# Modifying the Config class for Invoke

Tags: python, pyinvoke

I'm using the [Invoke](http://pyinvoke.org) python command runner and I'm having a bit of trouble making some modifications to the Config object (which loads and exposes user created options).

By default, Invoke will load a user profile with a prefix of `~/.invoke` (so it loads the file `~/.invoke.yaml` for example). The Config class, however, has an option to change this prefix to anything using the `user_prefix` option.

Unfortunately, there are no clear instructions as to where the config object has to be constructed and then used in the program?

I know that internally the config class in instantiated, the options are merged and exposed via the `context` variable within tasks, but where can I specify to use a different prefix for the user config file?

The `Program` class allows you to specify a config class in and of itself, but it will internally instantiate it with no option to set the `user_prefix`.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This is acutally a known issue in the current version of Invoke (0.14) and the devs are working on a fix

https://github.com/pyinvoke/invoke/issues/418

it will allow users to define a specific config file name if needed.